# amazon api : get all items from browsenode category

Tags: amazon-web-services

i am working with java.

i am using aws "itemsearch" to extract all the items from one browsenode at amazon.

i get a lot of results but because itempage is only up to 10 pages i cant get the other items from pages 11-300.

i know that i cant do this for a reason, but maybe their is another way to get to all the items from one category( without narrow down the items by adding  more parameters to the request.. because i need everything from this 'browsenode')

thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can get up to 100 results not 10 by the pagination 
Use the "ItemPage" attribute
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/PagingThroughResults.html

Comment: This answer is not valid as it returns the error if "ItemPage" attribute value is not between 1 to 10. So technically you cannot get  more than 100 results with same filter. Error - "The value you specified for ItemPage is invalid. Valid values must be between 1 and 10."